# Virtual hosting with nginx over SSL, without SNI (via a wildcard cert)

Tags: ssl, https, nginx

I'm trying to get https://survey.mediacru.sh to work without SNI. We have a wildcard cert and are using nginx as our http server. However, on browsers without SNI support (for example, the stock Android browser), https://mediacru.sh is served when you visit https://survey.mediacru.sh.

In theory, it should be possible to use a wildcard cert to handle virtual hosting without SNI. I can't seem to figure out how to set this up in nginx, though.

Our config files are available [on GitHub](https://github.com/MediaCrush/MediaCrush/blob/master/config/nginx.conf), for reference.

Comment: With a wildcard certificate you don't need SNI, as you are not delivering individual certificates per site. SNI also does not influence which site is served.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see anything wrong and with a simple test script with explicitly disabled SNI (checked with wireshark) I get the expected response based on the HTTP-Host header, e.g. if I set this header to survey.mediacru.sh I get the survey site, otherwise the default site. So whatever problem you have, it should not be related to SNI.